# Cannot get FlexSlider to work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ , which shows the a fairly familiar looking slider/carousel Jquery library but the left/right arrows (for previous/next image) are not showing in Firefox.

If you visit http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ you will note when you hover over the image, you get the left and right icon image (the arrows).

To simulate this, download the zip and extracted it. There is a index.html in the demo folder. Opening this and you will see the issue; everything works other than, this right and left arrow. When I hover over the slider, it doesn't display the left/right image

[image]

Firebug tells me there are no errors.

It works fine in IE and Chrome.

I went through the HTML file and checked all the javascript/css/images etc links work, and they appear to.

I will assume they don't work for any one, and if this is the case, what can I do to get the little left/right arrows?

**EDIT**

As per the comments

> The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol

My HTML code is (and I don't see any ASCII characters outside the US range)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">


    <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Demo CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Modernizr -->
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>


  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <!-- interseting use of defer, whcih means it wont' start until the page has loaded!!-->
  <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
</script>

<div style="width:650px; height:500px;">
 <div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li >
    <img src="images/slide4.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downloaded the same file and it's working fine. your problem must be something else. we can't troubleshoot what's there in your computer... try downloading again and run the `index.html` in `demo` folder without touching anything else.

Comment: @TilwinJoy, of course you can't debug this, I appreciate that. Would you do me a big favour and test in FireFox? For me, it is fine in IE and Chrome, just FF not working

Comment: it's working fine in safari as well… but not in firefox.. you might want to edit and rephrase the question regarding this...

Comment: `The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.` `ReferenceError: onTouchStart is not defined` plus two font download fails.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in a flexslider.css in this line

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
src:url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
src:url('fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

check the location of folder fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to always struggle using Jquery, but there usually is a way which works. Don't download what they give you as a download, instead, view the working example on their page, and copy the references directly.

EG, open all CSS files, and save them manually, the same for the images and JS files

As soon as I re-saved the CSS file and found the missing graphic, it worked as expected. I have no idea  why/how this worked in the other browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was to do with the error you see in Firefox when you view console in Web Developer Tools.

See error.

13:35:17.415 downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "flexslider-icon" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: file:my/local/paht/demo/fonts/webfonts/flexslider-icon.ttf1 demo.css:51:12

Once you have all your files on your server it will work.

Viewing offline/locally is the issue (only in FireFox).